# How to avoid a sql query in a forearch

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have 2 Tables: User and UserFriends

User
userID, Guid

UserFriends
 ActiveID, Guid - PassiveID, Guid

So you can be in my friendlist but I dont need to be in yours.
For an online list of all users, at first I get all user and Iterate them with a foreach to do things I have to do here.

```
List<DAL.User> onlineList = DAL.UserDAL.GetAllOnlineUser();
foreach (DAL.User onlineUser in onlineList)
{
   //do things here
    if (DAL.UserDAL.CheckForFriends(myUserID, onlineUser.UserID))
    {
           //Do things here
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
 public static List<User> GetAllOnlineUser()
    {
        using (RPGDataContext dc = new RPGDataContext())
        {
            return (from a in dc.Users where a.RefreshPing > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30) orderby a.Username select a).ToList();
        }
    }

public static bool CheckForFriends(Guid userActive, Guid userPassive)
    {
        using (RPGDataContext dc = new RPGDataContext())
        {
            UserFriend uf = (from a in dc.UserFriends where a.UserIDActive == userActive && a.UserIDPassive == userPassive select a).SingleOrDefault();
            return (uf != null);
        }
    }
```

In this foreach, i must check the friend and if, i blend in a friend-symbol in the onlinelist.
That means with 20 online Users without me, I have to go 20 times to the database and back.
How to avoid that?

Comment: Can't you get all the information loaded on the `GetAllOnlineUser()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are working with a relational database (e.g. Oracle, MySql, MsSql, etc.) ?

If so, let the database do what it does best: write a single query the returns the appropriate results from the database.

**UPDATE 1**

So for example, a MS SQL query might look something like:

```
SELECT u.userId, u.refreshPing
FROM userFriends f
JOIN [user] u ON u.userId = f.userFriendId
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, u.refreshPing, GetDate()) < 6000
AND f.userId = 1
```

For the sake of time, my query assumes that:

- the keys are integers (not GUIDs)
- user table = userId (int), refreshPing (DateTime)
- userFriends = userId (int), userFriendId (int)
- in my example userFriends.userFriendId is a foreign key back into the user table
- this query has not been tested

You would have to modify the query to match your schema... I have no idea how you are managing the friend relationships.

**UPDATE 2**
You could:

1. write a similar query using entity framework (I think this is the technology you are using)
2. create a view on the database and query the results
3. create a stored procedure and call it from your code

I would lean towards option #1.

**UPDATE 3**

Download LINQPad
www.linqpad.net/‎

Comment: Could you add a sample query that does this?  Or at least something to get the OP started?

Comment: I agree, pls deliver more then this hint :)

Comment: Thank you. I really cant treanslate T-SQL to Linq To SQL, can you form it in Linq to sql?
Of course the db is complete filled with FK and PK and so one, IDs are Guid.

Comment: As far as the logic is concerned to pull back a list of "friends online" a GUID or integer won't make a difference.

Comment: Great update, Pressacco.  I've removed my downvote and upvoted.

Comment: Thanks! I generally try to include an example but I was also helping a colleague troubleshoot a binary serialization/deserialization issue :D

Answer (score 2):

Create a query to return all of your friends before entering the `foreach` then just check each online user against that collection

Comment: Can you add code for this? Maybe within the GetAllOnlineUser-Query so I just need 1 query for that all?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to return a list of online users with added property for IsFriendOfCurrentUser? If you want to do this in single query you can't use the DAL entities in the UI layer.

Create separate classes for your UI and then select anonymous class with the online user details + boolean info if the current user is friends of that user. And exclude the current user from the list because you probably dont want to show the user that he is online.

```
public static List<InsertClassNameHere> GetAllOnlineUser(Guid userActive)
{
    using (RPGDataContext dc = new RPGDataContext())
    {
        var userList = from u in dc.Users
        join uf in dc.UserFriends on u.UserId equals uf.UserIDPassive into JoinedFriends 
        from uf in JoinedFriends.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where u.UserId != userActive
        select new 
        {
            UserId = u.UserId,
            IsFriend = uf != null ? true : false
        };

        var returnList = new list<InsertClassNameHere>();
        foreach(var user in userList)
        {
            returnList.Add(new InsertClassNameHere()
            {
                UserId = UserId,
                IsFriend = IsFriend 
            };
        }

        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var friends = onlineList.Where(a => a.UserIDActive == myUserID && a.UserIDPassive == userPassive);
```

or maybe i didn't understand the question.